# Spring binding exception when a form is submitted

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Stuck and have no clue why Spring Form is not able to submit successfully [gives binding issue] when pre-populated in get `Request` call `loadForm`, but works fine when populated in a method `setupFormObject` with `@ModelAttribute` annotation tag. I can provide a simple example in github to test out if asked for :)

Example below

```
@ModelAttribute("showForm")
public ShowForm setupFormObject() {
    //Instantiate showForm with data
    return showForm;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@RequestParam("id") String id, HttpSession session) {    
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(nextPage);
    //Instantiate showForm with data
    //modelAndView.addObject("showForm", showForm);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@ModelAttribute("showForm") ShowForm showForm, BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
     //I see changed data here in showForm when populated using @setupFormObject
     //See an exception in JSP with binding error if populated in loadForm
     return "";
 }
```

Stack Trace as requested. This exception is from [github](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke) example.

```
`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'users[0]' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'users' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Could not instantiate property type [com.example.UserEntity] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.UserEntity`

`type Exception report`

`message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'users[0]' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'users' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Could not instantiate property type [com.example.UserEntity] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.UserEntity`

`description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

`exception`

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'users[0]' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'users' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Could not instantiate property type [com.example.UserEntity] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.UserEntity`
    `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)`

`root cause`

`org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'users[0]' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'users' of bean class [com.example.UserForm]: Could not instantiate property type [com.example.UserEntity] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.UserEntity
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:829)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:556)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:533)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:894)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:699)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:595)
    org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:106)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
`
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I think more information is required here @java_dude, it will be great if you can provide a small project which replicates the behavior

Comment: Here is the link to the project that replicates the behavior https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke . Look at the / src / com / example / UserController.java. If you any questions regarding project do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Biju Were you able to try the example?

Comment: @java_dude post the JSP stacktrace please :)

Comment: @jelies Added stacktrace exception. Exception is from github example. HTH

Comment: Yes, tried it now, the issue is very small - UserEntity does not have a default constructor, if you add it your project works cleanly. Added as an answer also

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is actually that UserEntity does not have a default constructor, if you add the constructor it will work cleanly:

```
public UserEntity(){
    //
}
```

Comment: Vow! Spot on. That solved the problem. Its important to have the constructor public and not private either. I was following Static Factory Pattern and that resulted in the above stacktrace. Spring was not able to recreate the object without it. Thanks Biju.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the way your form is declared in the JSP, when submitting it it will assume that there is a `UserEntity` instance at position 0 in the `users` List of the `UserForm` instance, but it actually stumbles over a null reference.

Yes, you do add some UserEntity instances to the model when the form is displayed (using the loadForm method which is mapped to HTTP Get), but when you submit the form, a new model object is created, and this one will only have nulls in the users List.

Try making the model session scoped, this way the model instance you create when the form is shown will be reused when the form is submitted. Or create your own implementation of List that will return a new instance of UserEntity when a get(int position) is performed and there's nothing there.

Comment: yes I am seeing just the null when the form is submitted. I can try session scope but my other question is when the form is loaded with `@ModelAttribute("showForm")` is works perfectly fine. Do you know why does that happen. Debugger shows on submit `setupFormObject()` is called again. This is some what confusing me.

Comment: You're using @ModelAttribute in two places, once on a method and once on a field, and I'm not very sure to which one you refer in your above comment, but I'm guessing it's the one on the showForm method. I think this works for you because if you annotate the method like that, Spring will call that method each time it needs an instance of the "showForm" model (thus the list gets populated here as well). Without that annotation, Spring will just use the no arg constructor to instantiate the bean for the showForm model, hence all nulls in the list field.