# Spring Form binding issue during submission

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring Form is not able to submit successfully [gives binding issue] when populated in `Request` call `loadForm`, but works fine when populated in a method `setupFormObject` with `@ModelAttribute` annotation tag. I can provide a simple example in github to test out if asked for :)

I have spent couple of days searching and even using AutoPopulatingList but to no avail

Example below

```
@ModelAttribute("showForm")
public ShowForm setupFormObject() {
    //Instantiate showForm with data
    return showForm;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@RequestParam("id") String id, HttpSession session) {    
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(nextPage);
    //Instantiate showForm with data
    //modelAndView.addObject("showForm", showForm);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@ModelAttribute("showForm") ShowForm showForm, BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
     //I see changed data here in showForm when populated using @setupFormObject
     //See an exception in JSP with binding error if populated in loadForm
     return "";
 }
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring binding exception when a form is submitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234527/spring-binding-exception-when-a-form-is-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ModelAttribute` to a parameter named `showForm` of type `ShowForm` which is passed to the `loadForm` method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@RequestParam("id") String id, 
               @ModelAttribute("showForm") ShowForm showForm, HttpSession session) {    
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(nextPage);
    //Instantiate showForm with data
    //modelAndView.addObject("showForm", showForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Also make sure you are actually performing a GET request, I suspect this might be a post, which would require:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@RequestParam("id") String id,
```

Comment: I am passing ShowForm as a parameter to loadForm, as well as annotating that parameter with @ModelAttribute

Comment: Same issue still. I passed the ShowForm and then populated the data. Page loaded perfectly but failed during submission. Gave binding error. `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'someLists[0]' of bean class [com.example.ShowForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'someLists' threw exception;`

Comment: I tested in a simple example and it seems to be working :) I need to debug this further in the real code. But thanks for your help. I will surely keep you posted. Appreciate your help again :)

Comment: @Glad I could help.  If you need further help I would suggest posting the jsp.

Comment: Update: I was too quick to say it works :( I tested it and I can't get it to work. I have uploaded the sample code on https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke. Check out `UserController` that does exactly as you have mentioned.

Comment: @java_dude I just thought of something else you could check, I updated the answer.  I will checkout he github project when I get home later.

Comment: I have a debugger that gets called when the page loads. So for sure the `GET` request is being invoked. Also, thanks for looking into the project when you get home. If you have any question with loading the project let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the constructor. It was a private or missing public constructor. By adding a public constructor Spring was able to recreate the object

```
public UserEntity(){
   //
}
```

Link to solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234527/spring-binding-exception-when-a-form-is-submitted#comment19782508_14234527)