# Convert JSON to JAVA Object through play.data.Form

Tags: java, json, spring, playframework

I have no idea what to do with this problem.
I have a JSON object to assist in value input through POST (using Play Framework) that structures like this:

```
{
    "start_absolute": 1403185486254,
    "end_absolute": 1403185486254,
    "metrics": [
        {
            "name": "parts",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "key":"machine",
                    "value":"10"
                }
            ],
            "sampling": 
               {
                   "value": 1,
                   "unit": "minutes"
               }
         }
    ]
}
```

And in server side i try to process the info like this:

```
    Form<QueryForm> queryForm = Form.form(QueryForm.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (queryForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(queryForm.errorsAsJson());
    }

    QueryForm queryInfo = queryForm.get();
```

the classes used to define the JSON object in java

```
    public class QueryForm {

       private Date start_absolute;

       private Date end_absolute;

       private List<MetricForm> metrics= Lists.newArrayList();

       public Date getStart_absolute() {
        return start_absolute;
       }

       public void setStart_absolute(long start_absolute) {
        this.start_absolute = new Date(start_absolute);
       }

       public Date getEnd_absolute() {
        return end_absolute;
       }

       public void setEnd_absolute(long end_absolute) {
        this.end_absolute =new Date(end_absolute);
       }

       public List<MetricForm> getMetrics() {
        return metrics;
       }

       public void setMetrics(List<MetricForm> metrics) {
         this.metrics = metrics;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
            return "QueryForm[start_absolute="+start_absolute+", end_absolute="+end_absolute+", metrics="+metrics+"]";
       }
```

.

```
    public class MetricForm {

    private String name;

    private List<Tag> tags= Lists.newArrayList();

    private RelativeTimeForm sampling= new RelativeTimeForm(1,"milliseconds");

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags.addAll(tags);
    }

    public RelativeTimeForm getSampling() {
        return sampling;
    }

    public void setSampling(int val, String unit) {
        this.sampling.setUnit(unit);
        this.sampling.setVal(val);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MetricForm[name="+name+", tags="+tags+",sampling="+sampling+"]";
    }
```

.

```
public class Tag {

    private String key;

    private String value;

    public Tag(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
    return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
    return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
        public String toString() {
           return String.format(
                  "Tag[key=%s, value='%s']",
                   key, value
        );
        }
   }
```

.

```
        public class RelativeTimeForm {

    private int value;

    private String unit;

    public RelativeTimeForm (int val, String unit){
        this.setValue(val);
        this.setUnit(unit);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RelativeTimeForm[value="+value+", unit="+unit+"]";
    }
```

I'm not experienced working with play.data.Form but in previous ocasions with simpler objects (Using primitive data types and String) this worked fine but when i tried to POST to the play application (Header: Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8) it occurs an Internal Server Error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception [[InvalidPropertyException: 
Invalid property 'metrics[0].tags[0]' of bean class [model.QueryForm]: Illegal 
attempt to get property 'tags' threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 
'metrics[0].tags' of bean class [model.QueryForm]: Could not instatiate property
path: 
java.lang:InstatiationException: [model.Tag]
```

Any one can help with this? I can´t figure out what to do. Is it to complex of an object to convert from JSON? Do i need to add some JSON Annotations (not currently using them)?

I have no clue how to fix this

UPDATE: I narrowed it down to the Tag class. for some reason i'm not able to instatiate Tag through JSON. I even tried setting a single Tag instance in the same level as the dates and it gives the same error (It work for Sampling)

RESOLVED:

[Spring binding exception when a form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234527/spring-binding-exception-when-a-form-is-submitted)

The answer is in the post above. I have to set an empty construtor in Tag class for it to work.

```
public Tag(){

}
```

Comment: Use GSON for converting JSON to java objects

Comment: Have you looked [into the examples](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaJson)?

Comment: Yes but no example i found as an object inside alist of objects inside an object(Metric << List<Tag> << Tag). play.data.Form sets the dates and the name fine but is having trouble with Tags and Sampling

Comment: I narrowed it down to the Tag class. for some reason i'm not able to instatiate Tag through JSON. I even tried setting a single Tag instance in the same level as the dates and it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

The exception means, that one or more attributes aren't instantiated.

```
private List<MetricForm> metrics = new ...;
private List<Tag> tags = new ...;
private RelativeTimeForm sampling = new ...;
```

should do it.

In the case you get problems to read in your time values: Instead of using `Date` type directly to read in, I would use `long` to read in the time values and then (internally) convert them to `Date` objects.

Comment: I did as you told me but the error is the same. i updated the post with the complete classes. P.S.:nice catch on the date objects but i had fixed that one.